# Scientific short stay work (Schengen) visa in France but enter Italy first?

Tags: schengen, france, italy

I have a Schengen visa issued by France which is type C short stay scientific work visa (visa stamp has remark: scientific researcher), But i am looking to enter italy (Rome) and drive to France. Would that be a problem (1) from entry point of view at Rome airport on Schengen short stay (but not tourism) visa, (2) traveling in Italy on Schengen short stay (but not tourism visa) point of view.

Any suggestion/comment will be helpful.

EDIT: I am planning on traveling to Italy for tourism for 3 days before my work in France starts and I was warned by visa interviewer that traveling to Italy for tourism on work visa can result in denied entry to Italy. I am an Indian national traveling from US to Europe.

Comment: I am planning on traveling to Italy for tourism for 3 days before my work in France starts and **I was warned by visa interviewer that traveling to Italy for tourism on work visa can result in denied entry to Italy**. I am an Indian national traveling from US to Europe.

Comment: That's a different problem to arriving in a different country. I suggest you ask a new question about the visa use...

Comment: thanks Mark for suggestion.. just did [http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/47285/use-of-scientific-visa-schengen-short-stay-scientist-work-visa-issued-by-france]