# Use of scientific visa (schengen short stay scientist work visa issued by France) for tourism related travel to italy

Tags: schengen, working-visas

I have a Schengen visa issued by France which is type C short stay scientific work visa (visa stamp has remark: scientific researcher), But i am looking to enter italy (Rome) for 3 day long tourism and then drive to France. Would that be a problem (1) from entry point of view at Rome airport on Schengen short stay (but not tourism) visa, (2) traveling in Italy on Schengen short stay (but not tourism visa) point of view.

Any suggestion/comment will be helpful.

Further details: I am planning on traveling to Italy for tourism for 3 days before my work in France starts and **I was warned by visa interviewer that traveling to Italy for tourism on work visa can result in denied entry to Italy**. But she issued me the visa anyway that starts 3 days earlier from my work start date after looking at my hotels booking in Italy. I am an Indian national traveling from US to Europe.

Comment: Um, didn't you [already ask this exact question once](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/47279/scientific-short-stay-work-schengen-visa-in-france-but-enter-italy-first)?

Comment: @HenningMakholm I thought the same but apparently the other was about entering in a different country than your visa states and this one is about holidays in Italy with a French work visa.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A visa type C is a Schengen short-stay visa, and may be granted for "Academic/ scientific visit not exceeding 90 days".

My understanding of the procedure, as described on [that page of the French consulate](http://www.ambafrance-in.org/List-of-supporting-documents-to-be#tourism-5), and based on the [Official Journal](http://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=uriserv:OJ.L_.2005.289.01.0023.01.ENG) of the European Union, is that scientific researchers are given an easier entry into Schengen than tourists or some other visitors.

> Member States should take the necessary steps to make it easier for researchers to enter and move within the Community for short periods.

But once you are granted the visa, you are allowed to enter and visit any state of the Schengen area, this is a standard Schengen visa. Another [question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/39423/schengen-visa-for-both-business-and-tourism) would tend to confirm that point of view.

With this reasoning and a priori no explicit rule set by France/Schengen (e.g. a mention on the visa that would prohibit any other activity), you should be able to spend a few days for tourism in Italy. However, the rules are stricter when entering Schengen for tourism. In particular, you need medical insurance policy and a proof of funds. When arriving in Italy, it would be welcome or even mandatory to show that you already paid for your hotel or that you have enough funds for that, in case the border police ask. You can also simply take with you most or all of the documents listed [to apply for a tourism visa](http://www.ambafrance-in.org/List-of-supporting-documents-to-be#tourism-5).